# Running php script in console Win 8.1

Tags: php, windows

[image]

In the console as administrator, I am trying to run a PHP-script (all my scripts) and gives me the following: "**this app can't run on your PC**".

Before the last update everything worked and I ran this (and other) script 100 times.

PHP Version **5.3.27**, Windows **8.1**. In browsers all works. What a problem?

Answer (score 0):

**Installation files for the program you are trying to install got corrupted.**

Please visit this link

[same example](http://www.overclockers.com/forums/showthread.php?t=722938)

Comment: I'm not trying to install PHP) It has long been established)

Comment: @SET Ты, как всегда, до всего придираться )

Comment: @SET I mean apache http server.