# Running PHP in console of Windows 8.1

Tags: php, windows, windows-8, windows-8.1

Before an update some months ago everything worked. After required security updates for my **Windows 8.1**, I can't run **PHP** in console with admin rights. Running **PHP** via Apache (localhost) works.

[image]

**Translation:** You don't have access.

[image]

Please help me, because Microsoft support can't :) How can I add an exception in security of Win 8.1 for running **PHP** in console? How can I run PHP in console?

I'm crying... A lot of work has stopped.

Comment: This is a copy from your own question ...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21928496/running-php-script-in-console-win-8-1

Comment: How about installing Virtualbox and install a linux distro on it? Will solve a lot of problems for you and makes sure your development environment is the same as your production server. Or is your production running on Win 8.1? ;-) About the win 8 thing, did you try to add php a trusted publisher? I believe you can add those manually. Correct me if I'm wrong, it's too early to Google it for you :)

Comment: @Jelmer Ho can I to add php a trusted publisher?

Comment: @BohdanVorona http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733026.aspx it says win7 and win server 2008, but I think it's the same for 8. Just try to Google it. Why do you want to run php on your windows anyway? Can you tell it to us? Since I think if you use it as development environment there are better solutions :)

Comment: @Jelmer Although I have second comp with Ubuntu, I use Win, becouse I accustomed to it... Unfortunately...

Comment: Well, a linux distro isn't that different since you are already trying to use command line ... Command line is just not made for windows, I think it's best to try Virtualbox. I guess you are going to be happy ;-) A complete pro-tip would be: use Vagrant, but that might be above your head.